# Is LightDM is broken? Autologin works

Tags: 11.10, login-screen, lightdm

I recently upgraded my Mythbuntu box to 11.10.

LightDM worked for a while and then I configured autologin on my user account. After some time, I've removed some packages to lean down the system.

Now when I log out (from either Unity or Gnome Shell) I lose the X session, LightDM doesn't start back up.

If I disable autologin through `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` I get no login screen & no X.

As I said, autologin works and gives me a Ubuntu Classic desktop.

This is the only reference in `dmesg` to `lightdm`;

```
[   17.351023] type=1400 audit(1329530135.420:19): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session-wrapper" pid=1097 comm="apparmor_parser"
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Try to install `unity-greeter`.

I broke LightDM and this solved it, but I don't have the option to run Unity or Gnome Shell (they're installed).

Edit: I solved my problem installing 'gnome-session'.

Comment: Thanks, I think when I removed compiz the lightdm started having trouble, anyway, I re-installed everything to do with unity and gnome shell and all is good.